# select not adding pseudo after selector

Tags: html, css

I want to add a font-awesome arrow to my select but the `:after` selector does not appear to be being applied:

The focus is not being applied either for some reason.

```css
select {
  border: 1px solid #727272;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.select:after {
  content: "\F0DA";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
}

select:focus: {
  outline: 3px solid #ffbf47 !important;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select class="select">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't add `pseudo` element on `select`

Comment: you would need a wrapper element with the pseudo element to work.

Comment: Right. Where exactly do you want the icon to appear? Outside the control itself? And WRT your second question, that is being caused by a typo (the second colon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i said in comment you can not use `pseudo` on `select` instead wrap your select with a `div` then use `pseudo` on it.

```css
select {
    border: 1px solid #727272;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
.select-option {
position: relative;
width: 50%;
}

.select-option::after {
    content: "\F0DA";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 7px;
}

select:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #ffbf47 !important;
  outline-offset: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="select-option">
  <select class="select">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

If you want to use this arrow instead of default `select option` arrow on your select you need set `position: absolute` for `::after` element.

```
.select-option::after {
    content: "\F0DA";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 7px;
}
```

Don't forget to set `position: relative` on parent `.select-option` and i change your code a little for move `width: 50%` to `parent` and set `width: 100%` on `select`.

And note that, correct is `::after` not `:after`. `CSS3` introduced the `::after` notation (with two colons) to distinguish pseudo-classes from pseudo-elements. Browsers also accept `:after`, introduced in `CSS2`.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after).

And last word is, this is a common issue that you can't set `::after` or `::before` on `select option` possible there are many topics with this title, google, stackoverflow and etc.. anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas Pedram's answer is completely correct, it's worth noting that if you need to change the status of the `select` with Javascript it's difficult to manipulate a parent.

So, another approach is to use a `div` after the select

... some options

Then style that div by targeting `select + .indicator`.

In my case I had right and wrong selections in a quiz so to add a tick or a cross I used, eg, `select.correct + .indicator`

More than one way to skin a cat (or to correct an apparently illogical application of pseudo classes)